# Change the user data in FormsAuthenticationTicket programmatically

Tags: forms-authentication

I am using the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` and place the data and passing the data across all the pages.
and it will work if we are not changing any data.

So, now if I want to change the data and pass it for the cookie and encrypt then how to change the data programmatically.

Please give me the solution for changing the data in `HttpCookie` programmatically.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is an example of how I modify an already-issued forms auth ticket:

```
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(Username, true);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

// Store UserData inside the Forms Ticket with all the attributes
// in sync with the web.config
var newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                              ticket.Name,
                                              ticket.IssueDate,
                                              ticket.Expiration,
                                              true, // always persistent
                                              "User Data",
                                              ticket.CookiePath);

// Encrypt the ticket and store it in the cookie
cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);
cookie.Expires = newticket.Expiration.AddHours(24);
this.Context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Comment: i want to change the user data only then how is it possible?

Comment: The same code, just modify the "User Data" value to your value. The process (as far as I understand it) is the same regardless. Get the cookie, decrypt the ticket, update it, encrypt it, set the cookie in the response.

Comment: Why do you set the cookie expiration to `newticket.Expiration.AddHours(24)` instead of just `newticket.Expiration`?