# Get users security and info every request -> Else data gets stale

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

What we have currently implemented works well but I'm just concerned that there maybe a better way or we are doing it completely wrong.

Once logged into our website, ***on each and every request*** it will make a request to the API to get the users details.

E.g. Username, ImageUrl, Roles / Permissions, Email Address etc

It then stores this data in the BaseController for the viewpage or anyone else to see during that request.

**Upside:**
to doing it this way is that you know each request that the users permissions/roles and their details are all up to date!

**Downside:**
Your most likely to get exactly the same data every request, until that one day they change their details. Thus your possibly making unnecessary calls??

However the first way we tried all this was when the user logged in all their data gets stored in the cookie, the problem with this is that our users hardly ever logout so all the data that is stored in the cookie gets stale often. -> Stale Roles/Permissions is an annoying issue!!!

How does everyone get around the stale data from login.

Comment: `it will make a request to the API` - this refers to asp.net web api?

Answer (score 2):

I would go back to your initial approach of storing the claims inside the cookie.

If you do indeed have very long log in times then I would guard against stagnant claims by periodically refreshing the cookie.

If you are using forms authentication then you could intercept the `FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate` event in Global.asax, decrypt and manage the cookie ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402909/change-the-user-data-in-formsauthenticationticket-programatically)), validate the user and cookie first then run a quick conditional check against a custom field in the userdata property, called refreshedDate.

If the last refresh date or creation date is greater than some configurable window then call to the database and refresh the claim data from the database. Finally update the refreshDate and claim data and update the cookie.

**Update**

Following on from your comment...

Just to say that it is not uncommon to hit the database for each request, that is to say I have known it happen in a number of production systems. Many people are probably using [ASP.NET session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using MS-SQL database's. Typically I have seen it when there is a real security need to invalidate someone's session, deny access and log them out immediately.

If your database is on the network locally to your web servers and/or latency is acceptably low then it can be a perfectly workable solution. Just make sure your database queries are minimal and performance tuned to perfection, consider side steeping any ORM (if applicable) and use raw SQL connections to make things as fast a possible.

If database latency is high, the other middle ground solution is caching, using [Redis](http://redis.io/) or [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) to house the results of your queries and invalidating the cache when permissions are altered etc... but obviously adding the required infrastructure and operational support for caching solutions is a serious consideration.

Comment: Yeah I dont think I can get away with not storing the token in the cookie, this part of the process is working well. I am currently overrinding the FormsAuthentication in the Global Asax to do this. However I still think its a bit of a hack, to put in place a system that is going to fail every now and then....?

Comment: I guess, im just wondering if going to the api & getting this info foreach request is normal, are there people that do it?

Comment: If you already have a token - I just suggest adding a refresh date to it for the process of working out when to refresh the token... but agree this approach is a trade off i.e. won't prevent the token being stale 100% of the time, this merely reduces the window.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an expiration to the cookie; that way it dies and requires them to login.  Or, keep their user ID in the cookie, but store their profile info in session.  When session dies,  the next time the profile is checked if it is null, make a query to the API again.  This way, it's getting updated more frequently.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of expiring the cookie more frequently, as its not really an app that really needs to be all that secure. In reference to the session, there is still data that can be updated in which that data will become old and invalid. - And yip, I am referring to asp.net web api. Cheers

Comment: @Thwaitsey - I see you said yip, does that mean you are a new zealander?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other suggestions, another option may be to use a notification mechanism from the underlying role/permission store whenever a user's data changes. This notification could then be used to invalidate the cached data on the web server. This would ensure that the cached data is returned in the majority cases but the store would then be hit only when the data had changed.

If the underlying datastore is SQL Serevr then consider something like [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx).

This is obviously a more complex architecture but it would meet your requirement and only you could say whether it's worth the effort / complexity / tradeoff!